# I want to target the child element in the next sibling parent without using class or ID

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the html (which appears in multiple places but each appearance should be treated differently):

```
<div class="foot-nav-heading">Click me!</div>
    <div class="textwidget">
       <ul class="quick-link accordion-content">
          <li>Test</li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
var accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("foot-nav-heading");
  for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
     accordions[i].onclick = function() {
       this.classList.toggle('is-open');

   var content = this.nextElementSibling;
   if (content.style.maxHeight) {
   // accordion is currently open, so close it
 content.style.maxHeight = null;
   } else {
  // accordion is currently closed, so open it
 content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
   }
 }
}
```

I want to target the "ul" within the "div.textwidget" element. I've tried

```
var content = this.next.(".text-widget").find(".accordion-content")
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `this.querySelector('.accordion-content');`not sure if that works but try ;)

Comment: `document.querySelector('div.textwidget > ul.quick-link.accordion-content');`

Comment: Please note, the code below appears multiple times in multiple places:
 
    <div class="foot-nav-heading">Click me!</div>
         <div class="textwidget">
           <ul class="quick-link accordion-content">
              <li>Test</li>
           </ul>
    </div>

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll`...

Comment: @j08691
What will I replace with  "document.querySelector('div.textwidget > ul.quick-link.accordion-content');"?

Not so good with Javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code works! The problem is not the sibling, the problem is that you can't set css height to null

```js
var accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("foot-nav-heading");
  for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
     accordions[i].onclick = function() {
       this.classList.toggle('is-open');
   var content = this.nextElementSibling;

   if (content.style.maxHeight != "0px") {
   // accordion is currently open, so close it
 content.style.maxHeight = "0px";
   } else {
  // accordion is currently closed, so open it
 content.style.maxHeight = "200px";
   }
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="foot-nav-heading">Click me!</div>
    <div class="textwidget">
       <ul class="quick-link accordion-content">
          <li>Test</li>
       </ul>
</div>

Here is the javascript code:

<div class="foot-nav-heading">Click me!</div>
    <div class="textwidget">
       <ul class="quick-link accordion-content">
          <li>Test</li>
       </ul>
</div>

Here is the javascript code:
```

**EDIT** :
 What you have tried with your code is to get [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling). But you may have extra textnodes with carriage returns Try this snippet :

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".textwidget")[0].childNodes.forEach(function(el){
  console.log(el.nodeName,el.nodeType);
});
```

```html
<div class="foot-nav-heading">Click me!</div>
    <div class="textwidget">
    <ul class="quick-link accordion-content">
          <li>Test</li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

So trying to target directly would be risky (in your example you can get what you want with `content.childNodes[1]` but it'hazardous if you don't know how html is written. It could be `content.childNodes[0]` with no carriage return). Therefore the best option is to parse the childNodes and set a variable or push elements in an array when they fullfill the condition. in your case :

```
var ul;
content.forEach(function(el){
  if (el.nodeName === 'UL') ul = el;
}
```

or make an array from nodelist to filter desired node :

```js
var ul = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".textwidget")[0].childNodes).filter(function(el) {if(el.nodeName == 'UL') return el});

// or use es6 features
// var ul = [...document.querySelectorAll(".textwidget")[0].childNodes].filter(e => e.nodeName == 'UL');

console.log(ul[0]);
```

```html
<div class="foot-nav-heading">Click me!</div>
    <div class="textwidget">
       <ul class="quick-link accordion-content">
          <li>Test</li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But it works just fine where I cloned it from. Only difference is that the <ul> is enclosed in a <div> hence why I need to target the <ul> within the <div>

Answer (score 0):

## [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/event_capturing_bubbling_javascript.htm)

- Wrap all the accordions in a tag (`main#main`)
- Register the click event on this parent tag.
- Now any click on parent tag is detected by the tags nested within.
- By using [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), you can determine exactly which tag was clicked.
- This method can support an unlimited number of tags using a single [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)

---

### [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Concerning OP's objective:

> *"I want to target the child element in the next sibling parent without using class or ID."*

Considering the actual layout, each "button" can target `nextElementSibling` add/remove a class and still be able to affect the child of `nextElementSibling` by using CSS selector. In short, it is wasted effort and time to target a tag nested within a parent that is easier to access and in turn makes it easier to access it's descendants via CSS.

#### Layout

```
<button>CLICK</button>

<section class='accordion'>
  <ul class='list'>
    <li>ITEM</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

#### CSS

```
/* By default this hides .list */
.accordion {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border: 3px outset #666;
}

/* This class is added/removed when <button> is clicked */
/* .open is nextElementSibling and anytime .open is added, it's child .list 
   benefits from it as well
 */
.open,
.open .list {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 1000px;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border: 3px outset #666;
}
```

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Reference the parent tag (main#main)
var main = document.getElementById('main');

/*
Register <main> to the click event...
toggleText() is the callback function
*/
main.addEventListener('click', toggleText);

// Pass the Event Object (e)
function toggleText(e) {
  // Reference e.target -- clicked tag (header.head) 
  var tgt = e.target;
  /*
  Reference the next adjacent sibling of e.target (article.text)
  */
  var actTxt = tgt.nextElementSibling;
  // Collect all article.text into a NodeList
  var txts = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
  // if clicked tag has class .head...
  if (tgt.classList.contains('head')) {
    /*
    On each loop...
    if the current article.text is NOT e.target's .text sibling...
    ...remove class .open.
    Toggle .open class on e.target's .text sibling.
    */
    for (let i = 0; i < txts.length; i++) {
      if (txts[i] !== actTxt) {
        txts[i].classList.remove('open');
      }
    }
    actTxt.classList.toggle('open');
  }
}
```

```css
.head {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px outset #666;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.text {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border: 3px outset #666;
}

.open,
.open .menu {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 1000px;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border: 3px outset #666;
}
```

```html
<main id='main'>

  <header class="head">MENU</header>
  <article class="text">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>ITEM 1</li>
      <li>ITEM 2</li>
      <li>ITEM 3</li>
    </ul>
  </article>

  <header class="head">MENU</header>
  <article class="text">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>ITEM 1</li>
      <li>ITEM 2</li>
      <li>ITEM 3</li>
    </ul>
  </article>

  <header class="head">MENU</header>
  <article class="text">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>ITEM 1</li>
      <li>ITEM 2</li>
      <li>ITEM 3</li>
    </ul>
  </article>

</main>
```